# Capturing SIGTERM signal Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

So i finally found how to capture the signal from this site "https://pymotw.com/2/signal/" , I now can capture most of the kill signals like SIGINT, SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2.... all except the SIGTERM which heroku uses for some reason when I get a SIGTERM my script just exit instead of capturing the signal and do some work, Can Anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong? I'm testing with the command "kill -INT $pid", i can capture every kill signals Except the SIGTERM, THANKS....

Code :

```
run = false
def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    print("Received:", signum)
    global run
    run = False 

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, receive_signal)

print("My PID is:", os.getpid())

while run:
      main()
```

Comment: Where in your code are you repeatedly checking for the signal? I can see you do it once at the very beginning.

Comment: " while run: main() ", my problem is with capturing the SIGTERM signal not handling it, my code is working fine with others signals like SIGINT